# Feasibility problem of linear program for two distinct solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Let a linear program
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n}& \textbf{c}^{\text{T}}\textbf{x} \\
&\text{ s.t.}& \textbf{A}\textbf{x}&\leq \textbf{b},\\
&&\textbf{A}_{eq}\textbf{x}&= \textbf{b}_{eq}.
\end{aligned}
 Let $\textbf{A},\textbf{A}_{eq},\textbf{b},\textbf{b}_{eq}$ be such that there is some trivial feasible solution $\textbf{x}_0$ that satisfies the constraints, i.e, $\exists \mathbf{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ such that }\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_0\leq \textbf{b},\textbf{A}_{eq}\textbf{x}_0=\textbf{b}_{eq}$.

What is the best (read: fastest) method to find out, if there exists some other solution $\textbf{x}\neq \textbf{x}_0$ that satisfies the constraints? (Actually solving another feasible $\textbf{x}$ is unnecessary for my application.)

Ideally, this method would have implementations in some common optimization solver, such as Gurobi or Optimization Toolbox of Matlab.